# Variable In- output in ACT-R Chunk

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, trace

Given Unit1 standard ACTR documentary code:

```
(add-dm
(b ISA count-order first 1 second 2)
(c ISA count-order first 2 second 3)
(d ISA count-order first 3 second 4)
(e ISA count-order first 4 second 5)
(firstgoal ISA count-from start 0 end 5)
)
```

1. question:looking at the 0 and the 5 in den firstgoal chunk. Is it possible to declare that more generic like:

   ```
   (firstgoal ISA count-from start *global_start_var* end *global_end_var*)
   ```

---

2. Is it possible to output a specific value in an chunk? 
   Speaking of the counter I want a code running the model and then evaluate the number which the counter model counted to

Example how a lisp code might look like with proper value infiltration in the lisp model

```
    ;; load the model
    (load "counter.lisp")

    ;; set the start and end variables
    (setvar *global_start_var* 0)
    (setvar *global_start_end* 9)

    ;; run the model
    (run 9999)

    ;; safe the result of the counter in the (local) variable result using the function get_val
    (result (get_val))
```

Comment: The chance that you get ACT-R answers on Stackoverflow possibly is low. There is a mailing list: http://act-r.psy.cmu.edu/mailing-list/

Answer (score 0):

To set the chunk contents using Lisp variables you can use the add-dm-fct function which takes a list of chunk description lists:

```
(add-dm-fct (list (list 'firstgoal 'ISA 'count-from 'start *global_start_var* 'end *global_end_var*)))
```

To get the current value from the slot of a chunk you need to use the macro chunk-slot-value or the function chunk-slot-value-fct.  Those both take two parameters: the name of the chunk and the name of the slot, and then return the value of that slot in that chunk.
With the chunks you've shown there, this:

```
(chunk-slot-value b first)
```

will return 1.